# What's wrong with Super(Win) key, or maybe with Dash? Strange behavior

Tags: keyboard

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
desktop:GNOME

Maybe a strange question, but ...
After pressing Super(Win) key on keyboard, or by clicking by mouse on 'Dash' icon, I obtain a strange behavior of Ubuntu. Some application is run, and most of all input (from keyboard and mouse) are intercepted. This application have an icon in left-top corner with 'cross' icon, and pressing on it is closing the application that have an input focus.
And question is: what is that? And how to bring Super(Win) key to normal functionality?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the standard Ubuntu desktop? Edit your post and indicate Ubuntu version and desktop (`echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` in the terminal will show you the desktop used).

Comment: I use Gnome desktop. echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP => ubuntu:GNOME

Comment: So then please remove the "Unity-dash" tag, which wrongly suggests you are using the Unity desktop (default on Ubuntu until 17.04). Add to your question what Gnome extensions you have installed. You can see that in the tool "Extensions" (or in Gnome Tweaks, which is not installed by default).

Comment: Thank you! Your mind flow is correct! I have installed a 'Dash to panel' extension. And if I turn-off it, all comes correct. Maybe something wrong with this extension.

Comment: Strange. Is this "Dash to Panel by jderose9? That is normally a well maintained extension of very high quality. May be a combination with something else. Do you have your "close" button on windows on the left? You also have some extension that hides the title bar when maximized (such as Unite?).

Comment: Yes, I am using 'Dash to panel' by jderose9. And I don't have Unite extension or something else. Only two extension: 'Dash to panel' and 'Desktop icon'.  And I don't understand after what this happened. I didn't install anything or change some configurations. Nevertheless, at now I studying Java and just want a stable and working Ubuntu, and therefore 'Dash to panel' goes to off.